# Как правильно настроить Ext.chart.CartesianChart чтобы график не обрезался сверху?

Tags: extjs

Как сделать, чтобы числа над графиками не обрезались сверху?

Песочница https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1sqj

В ней видно, что август и декабрь сверху обрезан.